# execution within make rule

Tags: git, makefile

Is it possible to write a `make` rule that does not evaluate e.g. `$(shell )` expressions until previous operations have been executed?

An artificial example:

```
all : clean
    echo 'hey' > test
    echo $(shell cat test)

clean :
    rm test
```

then running `make` will result in the following error:

```
cat: test: No such file or directory
echo
```

The problem seems to be that `make` evaluates the `shell` command before going through the rules, so that `test` doesn't exist yet.  Is there a good way around this?

As background, what I am trying to do is write a make rule that checks out a different branch of a git repository and does things there in a way that requires evaluating e.g. `$(shell git ls-files)`; but `git ls-files` is evaluated before switching branches.

Comment: You might could say `echo 'hey' > test && echo $(shell cat test)`.

Comment: That would not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial workaround is to use the shell's own facilities. When executing a rule, you are already running shell commands.

```
all:
    echo 'hey' >test
    echo $$(cat test)
```

(Dollar signs meant for the shell need to be doubled, which is an escape to produce a literal dollar sign in Make.)

Obviously that's possible to refactor further, because the `echo` is [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo); but let's consider it as a placeholder for something useful.

Comment: Having said that, I suspect that what you are actually doing could be done a lot more elegantly. Care to post a new question with actual code, perhaps to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?